# Can I use Scrapy functions inside Django classes

Tags: python, scrapy

I have build a website in [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29). I need to use the web crawling features. So I installed Scrapy. Scrapy is working, as stated in their tutorial, by using

```
scrapy startproject dmoz
```

But that works on a diff folder with its own files.

Is it possible to use Scrapy functions in Django classes and put data in Django variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crawling is a long, time consuming task. It doesn't mix well with short HTTP requests. Therefore, you should use a user interface (presumably written in Django) to fire off Scrapy crawls, and a shared storage to monitor the state of the crawl.

But you wouldn't want to crawl during the lifetime of a HTTP requests. That's not how Scrapy is meant to be used.

Comment: But what if i just want to crawl single page or 2 pages  and that too in runtime.